# MongoDB and Multiple C# Client Threads

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a single primary instance of a MongoDB to connect to. I am using the C# driver (latest revision) to connect and utilise MongoDB.

My client application is multi-threaded whereby processes will run periodically at different intervals to produce reports. When more than one thread is running, and I call various functions on the driver (e.g server.DatabaseExists(...)), I am consistently met with an exception.

"The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"

```
 at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerAddress.ToIPEndPoint(AddressFamily addressFamily) in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoServerAddress.cs:line 195
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.GetIPEndPoint() in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoServerInstance.cs:line 339
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open() in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Internal\MongoConnection.cs:line 368
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.GetNetworkStream() in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Internal\MongoConnection.cs:line 574
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message, SafeMode safeMode, String databaseName) in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Internal\MongoConnection.cs:line 555
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetReply(MongoConnection connection, MongoRequestMessage message) in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoCursorEnumerator.cs:line 295
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetFirst() in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoCursorEnumerator.cs:line 253
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.MoveNext() in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoCursorEnumerator.cs:line 141
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase.GetCollectionNames() in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoDatabase.cs:line 645
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase.CollectionExists(String collectionName) in C:\work\rstam\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoDatabase.cs:line 297
```

Running one thread does not cause this issue. I am of the understanding that MongoDB is thread-safe, so I am at loss to understand the cause and the remedy.

Comment: So i'm having this exact same problem now, I have ruled out DNS by using an ip rather than hostname, did you make any progress?

Comment: @Stono.. Did using IP resolve your issue?

Comment: The error is happening outside of MongoDB driver - it's on the TCP/IP layer - the issue is with name resolution.  This is a Windows error, not MongoDB driver or DB error.  There are multiple hits if you google this error, all suggesting the issue is with hostname/host resolution.

Comment: btw, when you run one thread do you perform the same operations?  Is it specifically DatabaseExists() method or do all calls on second thread's connection cause this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "solution" I've found was to recycle the Application Pool that's hosting my website\service calling the mongo client.

Comment: I am going through old questions. Accepting this as the answer since it's the only one. Unfortunately I am no longer using MongoDB and I never resolved the issue myself.